# Is there a comma splice in this sentence found in a news article?

Tags: punctuation, comma-splices

The 26-year-old Frenchman’s strike-rate had caught the attention of Mourinho **,** his 129 goals in 275 games for Lyon made him an interesting prospect as a successor to Zlatan Ibrahimovic at Old Trafford.

It can be a non-essential statement set off by a comma but it's an independent clause too.

Was wondering can it be a case of comma splice over here?

Comment: It is indeed a comma splice, since two independent clauses are separated by only a comma.

Comment: @Scrooble: Thanks for your input. Nowadays, it's hard to read news articles that test your english proficiency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scrooble said, your example is indeed a comma splice. Independent clauses can't be seperated by a comma alone. In no particular order, here are some options on how to fix it:

A. Semicolon

> The 26-year-old Frenchman’s strike rate had caught the attention of Mourinho; his 129 goals in 275 games for Lyon made him an interesting prospect as a successor to Zlatan Ibrahimovic at Old Trafford.

B. Full Stop

> The 26-year-old Frenchman’s strike rate had caught the attention of Mourinho. His 129 goals in 275 games for Lyon made him an interesting prospect as a successor to Zlatan Ibrahimovic at Old Trafford.

C. Conjunction

> The 26-year-old Frenchman’s strike rate had caught the attention of Mourinho, and his 129 goals in 275 games for Lyon made him an interesting prospect as a successor to Zlatan Ibrahimovic at Old Trafford.

**Other notes**:
According to New Oxford American Dictionary, "strike rate" is not hyphenated.

According to some style manuals, particularly if you're writing ficiton, "26" would be written out: The twenty-six-year-old Frenchman's ...

Comment: thanks for your detailed explanation & suggested solutions to the rewrite of the sentence! :)